# Jasper iReport Variables Expression condition for char

Tags: variables, jasper-reports, ireport

I have a column in my database, which is the ColorCode column (Field name $F{COLORCODE} )  that has values like 'B' and 'R' and 'G', I want to count the amount of them respectively to their color.

So I have variables called countBlue, the variables expression is $F{COLORCODE}=='B' and put it in the Column Footer but the report counted everything including the R and G in that column, did I do the comparison statement wrongly?

also I have set up my countBlue variable class to java.lang.Integer, calculation as Count and reset type as Report

p/s sorry for bad english

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this expression (**Calculation**: *Count*; **Reset type**: *Report*; **Increment type**: *None*):

```xml
<variable name="countBlue" class="java.lang.Integer" calculation="Count">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{COLORCODE}.equals("B") ? "SomeNotNull" : null]]></variableExpression>
    <initialValueExpression><![CDATA[Integer.valueOf(0)]]></initialValueExpression>
</variable>
```

or this (**Calculation**: *Nothing*; **Reset type**: *Report*; **Increment type**: *None*):

```xml
<variable name="countBlue" class="java.lang.Integer">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{COLORCODE}.equals("B") ? $V{countBlue} + 1 : $V{countBlue}]]></variableExpression>
    <initialValueExpression><![CDATA[0]]></initialValueExpression>
</variable>
```

You can read about variables [here](http://www.jasperassistant.com/docs/guide/ch06s08.html).

The [JasperReports Ultimate Guide](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/JasperReports-Ultimate-Guide-3.pdf) says:

> **Calculation Count** 
>  
>   A count variable includes in the count the non-null
>   values returned after evaluating the variable’s main expression, with
>   every iteration in the data source. Count variables must always be of
>   a numeric type. However, they can have non-numeric expressions as
>   their main expression since the engine does not care about the
>   expression type, *but only counts for the non-null values returned,
>   regardless of their type*. 
>   Only the variable’s initial value expression
>   should be numeric and compatible with the variable’s type, since this
>   value will be directly assigned to the count variable when
>   initialized.